# Grails 3.2.4, IntelliJ 2016.3.4 there is a synthetic class generated for script code

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, integration-testing

All my integration test had that error message after upgrading from Grails 2.5.1 to 3.2.4. The upgrade includes moving the integration test from test/integration to src/integration-test. IntelliJ 2016.3.4 would not recognize the classes as test classes.

Answer (score 4):

In my case there was a groovy class with a method with excess closing brackets. I.e.:

```
class A {

   public void methodA() {
   }
 }
}

   public void methodB() {
   }
}
```

After removing double "}" my problem was solved.

Answer (score 3):

I had 2 package definitions in 1 file.

Comment: Slight variant for me - I had inadvertently started typing at the beginning of the file and corrupted my package statement so that it read 'requestpackage', which Groovy no longer recognized. Making it read 'package' again cleared the synthetic class error.

Answer (score 3):

I was also facing the same issue, If you see at your class in package explorer, will find that there is class inside your test class with the same name.

Copy code of your test class somewhere, Just delete your class(this way both the classes will be removed) and add it again and paste your code, my issue resolved by doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Changing my imports fixed the problem.

Old:

```
import grails.test.mixin.Mock
import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import grails.test.mixin.integration.Integration
import spock.lang.Specification
```

New:

```
import grails.test.mixin.Mock
import grails.test.mixin.integration.Integration
import grails.transaction.*
import spock.lang.*
```

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, I had to rename the class.  I didn't have the class name duplicate in the test classes and I didn't have an excessive closing bracket.

There's one thing that looks suspicious to me:

I have two groovy packages stored in app/src/main/groovy folder.  When I navigate to them in the Project Tab for either the Android view or Project Files view, I see both packages, but they have different icons proceeding them.  The first one has what looks like a java Class icon indicator and the second one has what looks like a groovy file indicator.  In the Android view, both of this files look like they are in the java folder.  It doesn't show me a groovy folder at all.  What I think may be happening is that android studio may be confused and think that I have the class duplicated in java and in groovy.  I think renaming the class got it unconfused.  I can assure you, I don't have any java classes defined in this custom plugin project.